# Sails.js One to many performances

Tags: node.js, sails.js, one-to-many, waterline

I have compared the sql query on sails.js with the other way of doing it, using waterline's ORM.

I did the following request : Get all countries from all continents and I compared both requests with wireshark.

The simple SQL query :

```
"SELECT * FROM countries AS cou INNER JOIN continents AS con ON (cou.continent_id=continent.id)"
```

And then I did the same defining a one to many associations between countries and continents and did the following request.

```
Continents.find().populate("countries").exec(function(err, result)) {
  res.send(result)
}
```

With that way, it takes around 66 ms to return the result, considering I have 15 ms of network delay, I can go down to 50 ms by moving the node.js server.

When I do it with the sql query, it takes around 35ms, so I could go down to nearly 20ms, which is good for me.

Is there a way to get the same results using both methods? or will the sql query always be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the query generated in such population is 
1. Selection of parents :

> select * from continent where ...

2. Selection of all countries of the retrieved continents.

> (select * from country where continent_id = continent_1)
>        union
>       (select * from country where continent_id = continent_2)
>        union
>        ...
>        union
>       (select * from country where continent_id = continent_n)

3. Regroup result (Affectation of every country to its continent by foreign key.

This implementation make easy the management of limit and skip clauses as the call :

> Continents.find().populate("countries").limit(2).skip(1).exec(function(err,
>   result)) {
>           res.send(result)
>        }

should only return the second and the third country for every continent and such implementation as you can see generate one only query so DBMS will not be overloaded.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it, but when it comes to returning everything, it's really slow, and even sorting the result with limit and skip, it's still slower than an SQL query

Comment: In this case, i suggest using 
Continent.query(your_query,function(err,res){});
And group yourself your result to affect every child to its parent.

Comment: Yes, but my point is, is it worth to use waterline if I can't get the performances I am expecting?

Comment: Maybe you can put it as an issue on github, it's not a waterline issue as the implementation of join interface (the adapter method that deals with populate() function)is done by adapters developers. You can put an issue on sails-MySQL or sails-oracle or any other waterline adapter.